# Альтернатива for(key in array)

Tags: массивы, javascript, циклы

Говорят что в JavaScript не желательно использовать `for(key in arr){}`.

Имеется массив типа `arr["Ab"=>5;"cBa"=>3]` я не знаю имена ключей ("Ab" , "cBa" и т.д). Раньше я переберал его так:

```
for(key in arr){
  var val=arr[key];
  alert(val);
}
```

но даже WebStorm (моя IDE) говорит что ***очень нежелательно*** использовать `for(key in arr){}`. 
Вопрос: есть ли альтернатива `for(key in arr)` для массивов ключи у которых не цифры

Comment: А не говорит почему?

Comment: Потому что например в for(var key=0;key<arr.length;kuy++) может выявить ошибку а в for in это проблематично ps ошибка в kuy++ вместо key++

Comment: А ещё for in в IE<9 выдаёт неожиданные ошибки :(

Comment: Я бы сказал не неожиданные, а внезапные :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[[@Rules](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules) - открой уже для себя то, что массивы должны иметь целочисленные ключи, для строковых ключей испльзуются объекты, несмотря на то, что использование for in в принципе не самое быстрое решение, но для объектов оно приемлимо (структура объекта заранее не известна, по другому никак), соответственно, javascript way:

```
var hash = {
  Ab  : 5 ,
  cBa : 3
}
for( var i in hash ) {
  if(hash.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
     // hash[i] ...
  }
}
```

Более оптимальный способ:

```
var hashKeys = Object.keys( hash );
for( var i=0, l=hashKeys.length; i<l; ++i ) {
    // hash[ hashKeys[i] ]
}
```

Но метод Object.keys, к сожалению, работает не везде.

Вообще, как я понял, ты пытаешься перенести свои знания PHP на JavaScript, так вот - не нужно этого делать, это 2 абсолютно разных языка. В PHP, на самом деле, массивов, как таковых - вообще нет, там array используются практически для всего, для хэшей, для стэков, очередей и много другого. В JavaScript же есть стандартные массивы (не совсем стандартные т.к. являются объектами, но это особенность любого типа данных в JavaScript, для стэков и очередей так-же используют их) их нужно использовать тогда, когда все элементы структуры должны иметь целочисленные ключи, если же тебе нужен ассоциативный массив (хэш), тогда использую тип данных который для этого предназначен, а именно Object

На самом деле, когда ты делаешь что-то типа `arr["stringKey"] = "someValue"` - это не то-же самое что и в php `$arr['stringKey'] = 'someValue';`, в JavaScript'e это просто динамическое определение кастомного свойства для массива(объекта), так-же как и, например - `function a (){}; a.stringKey = "someValue"`.

PS: небольшое дополнение, вместо `for( i in someObject )` используйте `for( var i in someObject )`. Пояснение:

```
var i = [1,2,3,4]; // моя глобальная переменная i
var o = {
  "name" : "Vasya"
}; // какой-то объект
for( i in o ) {/*....*/}
console.log(i); // WTF? i === "name"
// т.е. не используйте дабы не иметь риска
// перезаписать ранее объявленную глобальную переменную
// к тому-же доступ к глобальным переменным медленее
// чем к локальным
```

PPS: небольшой оффтоп, просто многие не знают и, думаю, многим будет интересно. На самом деле в PHP то-же есть очередя и стэки (и не только они), например стэк можно создать так:

```
$stack = new SplStack();
$stack->push(1);
$stack->push(2);
$stack->push(3);
// для извлечения
$stack->pop();
```

Практически так-же можно создать очередь:

```
$queue = new SplQueue();
$queue->enqueue(1);
$queue->enqueue(2);
$queue->enqueue(3);
// для извлечения
$queue->dequeue();
```

Ответы на вопросы - в чем их преимущества, есть ли еще подобные типы данных и т.д. и т.п. вам поможет найти великий и могучий гугл =)

---

UPD:

Еще когда писал ответ - не хотел быть голосовным в вопросе обхода свойств объекта в JavaScript, но ссылка на бенчмарк была потеряна.

Собственно [вот](http://jsperf.com/object-keys-vs-hasownproperty) бенчмарк. Цикл for, по object.keys медленее только в лисе. И то, связано это с тем, что у лисы абсолютно иначе работает JS движок, да и дегрейд там незначителен, но, например, в chrome - это быстрее, примерно, в 10 раз.

PS: естественно при написании современных ( наплевав на все старье ) JavaScript либо Node.js приложений ( да тот-же десктоп или приложений под моб.устройства ) лучше всегда использовать подход Object.keys с последующим циклом по нему.

Comment: Стоит отметить, что в приведенном в PS примере и `for( i in someObject )`, и `for( var i in someObject )` приводят к одному и тому же результату в консоли — "name".
А вот `for( let i in someObject )` действительно работает так, как задумано. Однако не все браузеры такое понимают.

Answer (score 1):

Разве в джава-скрипте отменяли перебор while() или классический способ от [[@Rules](/users/1267/rules)](/users/1267/rules) ?

```
for (var kuy = 0; kuy < arr.length; kuy++)
```

> Перебирающие методы
>
> **forEach**
>
> Метод `arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])` вызывает функцию `callback` для каждого элемента массива.
>
> **filter**
>
> Метод `arr.filter(callback[, thisArg])` создаёт новый массив, в который войдут только те элементы arr, для которых вызов `callback(item, i, arr)` возвратит `true`.
>
> **map**
>
> Метод arr.map(callback[, thisArg]) создаёт новый массив, который будет состоять из результатов вызова callback(item, i, arr) для каждого элемента arr.
>
> **every/some**
>
> Метод `arr.every(callback[, thisArg])` возвращает true, если вызов `callback` вернёт `true` для каждого элемента `arr`.
>
> Метод `arr.some(callback[, thisArg])` возвращает true, если вызов `callback` вернёт `true` для какого-нибудь элемента `arr`.
>
> **reduce/reduceRight**
>
> Метод `arr.reduce(reduceCallback[, initialValue])` применяет функцию `reduceCallback` по очереди к каждому элементу массива слева направо, сохраняя при этом промежуточный результат.

[Источник](http://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#foreach) для самых любознательных =)

Comment: офигенный копипастер =)

Comment: Конечно качество копипаста оставляет желать лучшего :) Но всё равно спасибо никогда не слышал про forEach в JavaScript

Comment: все эти методы массивов пропустят все не цифровые ключи