# Как добавить свойство в конец вложенного объекта?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть такой объект:

```
var rooms = { 
    '/#IHT50E5Ds0jZdY_RAAAA': { room_name: 'NEW_ROOM1', name_owner: 'GUEST1' },
    '/#NqtUF7Y3VZtH4OaVAAAC': { room_name: 'NEW_ROOM2', name_owner: 'GUEST2' }
}
```

Как можно из него получить такой:

```
var full_rooms = {
    '/#IHT50E5Ds0jZdY_RAAAA': { room_name: 'NEW_ROOM1', name_owner: 'GUEST1', users: 1 },
    '/#NqtUF7Y3VZtH4OaVAAAC': { room_name: 'NEW_ROOM2', name_owner: 'GUEST2', users: 1 } 
}
```

Т.е. добавить свойство в каждый объект?

Никак не могу привыкнуть синтаксису JS в работе с объектами, из-за этого ничего не получается :(

Comment: Разбейте задачу на более простые. Для начала, вам надо перебрать все значения вашего словаря. Потом - добавить каждому свойство. По отдельности ответ на эти подзадачи найти проще, чем вместе.

Comment: До первого пунтка я дошёл. `for (var room in rooms) { 'что делать тут, не знаю '}`

Comment: Ну а второй вообще элементарный - `obj.users = 1`, где obj - объект, полученный в первом пункте.

Comment: Только вот первый пункт бы немного неправильно сделали. Надо же получить значения в словаре - а вы ключи получили.

Comment: Уф, каким же образом тогда  правильно разобрать объект room? Читаю ответ на этот [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/109866/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-forkey-in-array) и что из этого подойдёт?

Comment: этот вопрос не подходит, потому что в текущем вопрос **объект**, а в том **массив**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

изменил:

```
 var rooms = { 
            '/#IHT50E5Ds0jZdY_RAAAA': { room_name: 'NEW_ROOM1', name_owner: 'GUEST1' },
            '/#NqtUF7Y3VZtH4OaVAAAC': { room_name: 'NEW_ROOM2', name_owner: 'GUEST2' }
        }
        var full_rooms= {};

        for (var item in rooms){

          full_rooms[item] = rooms[item];
                full_rooms[item].users = 1;
        }

            console.log(full_rooms);
```

если нужно сохранить исходник:

```
 var rooms = { 
        '/#IHT50E5Ds0jZdY_RAAAA': { room_name: 'NEW_ROOM1', name_owner: 'GUEST1' },
        '/#NqtUF7Y3VZtH4OaVAAAC': { room_name: 'NEW_ROOM2', name_owner: 'GUEST2' }
    }
    var full_rooms= {};

    for (var item in rooms){
        full_rooms[item] = {};
            for(var x in  rooms[item]){
              full_rooms[item][x] = rooms[item][x];
            }
            full_rooms[item].users = 1;
    }


        console.log(full_rooms);
        console.log(rooms);
```

Comment: Объекта full_rooms как бы нет. Его нужно создать из rooms

Comment: `item` в данном случае это строка, название свойства, а не значение

Comment: @Literate ставте вопрос конкретние... "дубликат объекта с новым свойством(полем)"..

Comment: Да, хорошо. Видимо недостаточно правильно сформулировал вопрос. Спасибо за ответ, постараюсь более не тупить так.

Comment: @Literate осторожнее - если вам нужна копия исходной структуры с новым полем - то примите во внимание, что новое поле в этом коде появляется не только у копии.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Мне объект rooms не нужен, после этих манипуляций, но как так получилось? В какой момент кода rooms меняется? (это мне для самообразования)

Comment: @Literate,  Pavel Mayorov все правельно. добавил с сохранением исходника...

Comment: @Literate объект rooms не менялся. Менялись те объекты, которые в нем лежали (старая версия кода их не создавала их копий)

Comment: @Literate кстати, зачем вам создавать новый объект `full_rooms` - если старый объект `rooms` больше не нужен? Все будет куда проще, если переиспользовать старый.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov логично да, поправил у себя код, теперь не дублирую объекты.